# Initializing enum with int in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I know that we can initialize an `enum` with a value from its underlying type (by default, that’s `int`). Therefore, `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` is 0, 1, and 2, respectively.

```cpp
enum class Color {
    Red, Green, Blue
};
```

My question: if an object of an `enum` does not equal to any instance of an `enum`, is it enum logically? For me, I think `enum` means a finite possible values. I don't understand the design choice behind it.

```cpp
Color c{7};
// c not equal to any one
std::cout << (c == Color::Red) << std::endl;
std::cout << (c == Color::Green) << std::endl;
std::cout << (c == Color::Blue) << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Eljay Scoped enums (`enum class`) have a fixed underlying type, even if none is specified (`int` in that case) and therefore the range restriction doesn't apply. That's only for unscoped enums without explicit underlying type. But, given that easy confusion, I guess one really shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: It is simply a design choice. With the exception we discussed above (i.e. if you change `enum class` to just `enum`), an enumeration type can always hold all values of its underlying type (`int` in your case). The enumeration simply permits one to give some of these values specific names. It isn't intended for only the use case that all possible values are named. You can image an enumeration type that is supposed to be similar to an integer type where certain values are special and should have a name as well or a type that represents a combination of named bit flags.

Comment: *is it enum logically?*  **Yes**, the scoped enum is a type.  *I don't understand the design choice behind it.*  Consider `enum class byte : unsigned char {};` which is a separate type ... it has no enumerations; if it were constrained to only enumerated values, it would need to 256 enumerations from `0` to `255`.  That'd be a bit of a bother.  Too bad we can't do `enum class x_coord : float {};` to get a non-aliasing type.

Comment: I can understand why you're puzzled. But explicit construction seems to be the only way to get illegal values into a scoped enum. Assignment (`c=6;` ) is not possible. I can only suspect that the decision was to keep *one* way open to have any value in that type; in explicit creation you make it clear that you deliberately want to leave safe grounds.

Comment: Enums can have other values than their specified ones, as long as they still fit in the underlying type. That's perfectly valid and within the C++ specification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is logical. If you don's specify a type, then the type of each enumeration will be an unspecifed signed integral type. And every enumerator should be of the same type of the preceding enumerator unless the the value is not represenatble in the unspecifed signed integral type that is used for the enum.